# Google maps layer for strategic game

Tags: 2d, maps, tilemap

I found one web site http://e-sim.org/googleMap.html which is similar to my game idea. But I have no experience on game maps developing. Can anyone share ideas how to make similar functionality like that map, for example how indicate neighborhood position? Any better ideas for 2d map

Comment: Having a linked example is a great supplement to a written description, but you still want to tell us "I'm trying to implement such and such feature; here's an explanation: here's an example:"

Comment: Some examples of google maps api usage: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polygons_v3